# How to elegantly extract range of list based on specific criteria?

Tags: scala, collections

I want to extract range of elements from a list, meeting the following requirements:

- First element of range has to be an element previous to element matching specific condition
- Last element of range has to be an element next to element matching specific condition
- Example: For list (1,1,1,10,2,10,1,1,1) and condition `x >= 10` I want to get (1,10,2,10,1)

This is very simple to program imperatively, but I am just wondering if there is some smart Scala-functional way to achieve it. Is it?

Comment: Do you mean `x >= 10` as condition?

Comment: Right! Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: If something like this is simple to program imperatively, there is nothing wrong with just doing so as long as all your mutable state is local. Write a few tests for the corner cases to make sure you don't have an off-by-one or other typical imperative error, and just move on. 

See these slides from Scala Days 2013 from Martin Odersky himself (Slide 26 to 30):
http://de.slideshare.net/Typesafe/scaladays-keynote

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn, your comment makes a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: And yet it is always worth examining how Scala's combinator functions might solve the problem.  The result isooften more efficient and even when not, may well be more expressive and more apt for generalisation

Comment: Marcin, drexin has quite fairly interpreted your requirements as meaning that elements which match the criteria but fall at the beginning or end of a list should be excluded. Is that the case or not?

Comment: What would be the correct output for each of the following lists?  `List(10)`, `List(10,2,1)`, `List(2,10,1,10)` and `List(1,10,9,8,7,10,6,5)`?  Your question is ambiguous enough that almost every person trying to answer this has made different assumptions.  For example, `f(List(1,10,9,8,7,10,6,5)` *could* return `List(1,10,9,7,10,6)`, `List(1,10,9)` or even `List(1,10,9,8,7,10,6)` - each would be a fair interpretation of your question.  If you could update your answer to show the proper results for these edge cases, it would remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Or at least you could indicate which of the answers has made the right assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it in the scala standard lib, I would solve this using recursion:

```
def f(_xs: List[Int])(cond: Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
  def inner(xs: List[Int], res: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: y :: tail if cond(y) && res.isEmpty => inner(tail, res ++ (x :: y :: Nil))
    case x :: y :: tail if cond(x) && res.nonEmpty => res ++ (x :: y :: Nil)
    case x :: tail if res.nonEmpty => inner(tail, res :+ x)
    case x :: tail => inner(tail, res)
  }

  inner(_xs, Nil)
}

scala> f(List(1,1,1,10,2,10,1,1,1))(_ >= 10)
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 10, 2, 10, 1)

scala> f(List(2,10,2,10))(_ >= 10)
res4: List[Int] = List()

scala> f(List(2,10,2,10,1))(_ >= 10)
res5: List[Int] = List(2, 10, 2, 10, 1)
```

Maybe there is something I did not think of in this solution, or I missunderstood something, but I think you will get the basic idea.

Comment: It is bad style to have that second list in the parameters.  You should really wrap this in an outer function which only takes one list and a predicate. As it is, you are leaking implementation detail. It is a potential source of error and what if you change the implementation?

Comment: More importantly, your function does not work,  as you should realise if you properly read the output of your own tests. `f (List (2, 10 2, 10))(_ >= 10)` should result in `List (2, 10, 2, 10)` and not Nil.

Comment: You are right with using an inner function, but the result is correct, as it matches the OPs requirements: 'Last element of range has to be an element next to element matching specific condition'

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't *think* the questioner meant to omit cases where units which match are the first or last element of this list, but it is a fair and literal way to read his spec.

Answer (score 2):

Good functional algorithm design practice is all about breaking complex problems into simpler ones. 
The principle is called [**Divide and Conquer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).

It's easy to extract two simpler subproblems from the subject problem:

1. Get a list of all elements after the matching one, preceded with this matching element, 
   preceded with an element before it.
2. Get a list of all elements up to the latest matching one, followed by the matching element and
   the element after it.

The named problems are simple enough for the appropriate functions to be implemented, so no subdivision is required.

Here's the implementation of the first function:

```
def afterWithPredecessor
  [ A ]
  ( elements : List[ A ] )
  ( test : A => Boolean ) 
  : List[ A ] 
  = elements match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case a :: tail if test( a ) => Nil // since there is no predecessor
      case a :: b :: tail if test( b ) => a :: b :: tail
      case a :: tail => afterWithPredecessor( tail )( test )
    }
```

Since the second problem can be seen as a direct inverse of the first one, it can be easily implemented by reversing the input and output:

```
def beforeWithSuccessor
  [ A ]
  ( elements : List[ A ] )
  ( test : A => Boolean ) 
  : List[ A ] 
  = afterWithPredecessor( elements.reverse )( test ).reverse
```

But here's an optimized version of this:

```
def beforeWithSuccessor
  [ A ]
  ( elements : List[ A ] )
  ( test : A => Boolean ) 
  : List[ A ] 
  = elements match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case a :: b :: tail if test( a ) => 
        a :: b :: beforeWithSuccessor( tail )( test )
      case a :: tail => 
        beforeWithSuccessor( tail )( test ) match {
          case Nil => Nil
          case r => a :: r
        }
    }
```

Finally, composing the above functions together to produce the function solving your problem becomes quite trivial:

```
def range[ A ]( elements : List[ A ] )( test : A => Boolean ) : List[ A ] 
  = beforeWithSuccessor( afterWithPredecessor( elements )( test ) )( test )
```

### Tests:

```
scala> range( List(1,1,1,10,2,10,1,1,1) )( _ >= 10 )
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 10, 2, 10, 1)

scala> range( List(1,1,1,10,2,10,1,1,1) )( _ >= 1 )
res1: List[Int] = List()

scala> range( List(1,1,1,10,2,10,1,1,1) )( _ == 2 )
res2: List[Int] = List(10, 2, 10)
```

The second test returns an empty list since the outermost elements satisfying the predicate have no predecessors (or successors).

Answer (score 1):

```
def range[T](elements: List[T], condition: T => Boolean): List[T] = {
   val first = elements.indexWhere(condition)
   val last  = elements.lastIndexWhere(condition)

   elements.slice(first - 1, last + 2)
}

scala> range[Int](List(1,1,1,10,2,10,1,1,1), _ >= 10)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 10, 2, 10, 1)

scala> range[Int](List(2,10,2,10), _ >= 10)
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 10, 2, 10)

scala> range[Int](List(), _ >= 10)
res2: List[Int] = List()
```

Comment: This solution is pretty good at the first glance. At the second look you might recognize, that 'elements.lastIndexWhere(condition)' always runs through the entire list. Whereas 'elements.indexWhere' runs until the first appliance of the condition. Slice also runs until the second index. At worst you might run 3 times through the entire list. At average you run half the list for 'first', the entire list for 'last' and eventually two third of the list for slicing it. So you might consider going for a recursive solutin, which just needs one traversion.

Comment: Yes i knew that from performance point of view, the solution is not performing well especially lastIndexWhere because of head/tail nature of scala lists. For small list it makes sense because it is much more readable with not considerable performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Zip and map to the rescue

```
val l = List(1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1)

def test (i: Int) = i >= 10

((l.head :: l) zip (l.tail :+ l.last)) zip l filter {
  case ((a, b), c) => (test (a) || test (b) || test (c) )
} map { case ((a, b), c ) => c }
```

That should work. I only have my smartphone and am miles from anywhere I could test this, so apologise for any typos or minor syntax errors

Edit: works now.  I hope it's obvious that my solution shuffles the list to the right and to the left to create two new lists. When these are zipped together and zipped again with the original list, the result is a list of tuples, each containing the original element and a tuple of its neighbours. This is then trivial to filter and map back to a simple list.

Making this into a more general function (and using `collect` rather than filter -> map)...

```
def filterWithNeighbours[E](l: List[E])(p: E => Boolean) = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case li if li.size < 3 => if (l exists p) l else Nil
  case _ => ((l.head :: l) zip (l.tail :+ l.last)) zip l collect {
    case ((a, b), c) if (p (a) || p (b) || p (c) ) => c
  }
}
```

This is less efficient than the recursive solution but makes the test much simpler and more clear. It can be difficult to match the right sequence of patterns in a recursive solution, as the patterns often express the shape of the chosen implementation rather than the original data. With the simple functional solution, each element is clearly and simply being compared to its neighbours.

Comment: Downvote, because it does not yield the correct result. `List(1, 10, 2)` where it should have been `(1,10,2,10,1)`.

Comment: @drexin, your downvote is not fair or accurate.  You haven't read my code properly.  Look at the data input - `val l = List(1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1)` and my output is correct for that case.  If you give it the input `val l = List(1, 1, 1, 10, 2,10, 1, 1, 1)`, the output is just as the questioner want.  You should have read and tested it more carefully.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It is however not quite clear from OPs post, what it should yield in that case.

Comment: You might want to consider using `collect` instead of `filter` + `map`.

Comment: You are right, but in my defence I wrote this while in a muddy field in France and couldn't test it ;)